# PHP Replace basename in the URL

Tags: php

I have this function.

```
function getCallbackUrl(){
    $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . 'response.php';
}
```

On my URL `http://localhost/gateways/payu/index.php` the above function displays URL like this `http://localhost/gateways/payu/index.phpresponse.php`. No idea why it is happening. The function seems correct to me. Maybe I am missing out something that I am not able to replace the base name from `index.php` to `response.php`. Any help would be truely appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` itself has `index.php`, hence you are facing this issue, where `response.php` is concatenated instead of replacing. A quick fix is as below:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'response.php',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You can *also* use a combination of [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php),[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to achieve this.

- Parse the url and get the URI path.
- Get the basename of the URI.
- Replace it with the one you want to.
- Join these pieces together and return the URL.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


function getCallbackUrl($url,$replacement_file){
    $url_data = parse_url($url);
    $url_data['path'] = str_replace(basename($url_data['path']),$replacement_file,$url_data['path']);
    $url = $url_data['scheme'] . "://" .  $url_data['host'] . $url_data['path'];
    if(!empty($url_data['query'])) $url .= '?' . $url_data['query'];
    return $url;
}



echo getCallbackUrl('http://localhost/gateways/payu/index.php','response.php');
```